# MUI v5: Failed prop type: The prop `direction` of `Grid` can only be used together with the `container` prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm styling a MUI v5 `Grid` as follows:

```js
const SettingsGrid = styled(Grid)(({ theme }) => ({
    width: `calc(100% - calc(${Number(theme.spacing(2))} * 2))`,
    margin: theme.spacing(2),

    '& .MuiCard-root + .MuiTypography-subtitle1': {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
    },
}))
```

Then, I'm using it as follows:

```js
<Box m={1} overflow="auto">
  <SettingsGrid
      container
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
  >
      <Grid
          direction="column"
          style={{ minWidth: '35em', maxWidth: '60em' }}
      >
          <!-- ... -->
      </Grid>
    </SettingsGrid>
</Box>
```

This now throws this console warning at runtime:

```
Failed prop type: The prop `direction` of `Grid` can only be used together with the `container` prop.
```

I've tried with `container={true}` but this doesn't help. It seems as if the `container` property gets lost in `styled()`. How can I fix this? I'm at a loss.

EDITH: https://codesandbox.io/s/gritty-styled-grid-7l04g

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem.

Comment: @TheDiveO Try setting `container` in the inner `Grid`, I think you're missing the `container` prop there. Confirmed on Codesandbox that it works with or without `styled`.

Comment: Added sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gritty-styled-grid-7l04g

Comment: Arg, thank you. It's the inner Grid, not the outer Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `direction` prop of your `Grid` is only valid if the `container` prop is set to `true`, so add the missing `container` prop in your inner `Grid`. Internally, a container `Grid` has the display set to `flex`, and the `direction` is mapped to `flex-direction`, `flex-direction` is meaningless if the layout is not flex:

```
<Grid container direction='column'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what NearHuscarl has mentioned, this is the place where you are missing the `container` prop.

```
<Box m={1} overflow="auto">
  <SettingsGrid
      container
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
  >
      <Grid
          container  <<<------------------ you are missing this 
          direction="column"
          style={{ minWidth: '35em', maxWidth: '60em' }}
      >
          <!-- ... -->
      </Grid>
    </SettingsGrid>
</Box>
```

Comment: Thanks, noticed that ... finally.